# How to use a OnClick Event on a <td> to change Visiblity of a DIV

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I am having a DIV in which I have a table. When User click on the TD i want to change the visibility value of another DIV on the same page. Below is my code.

I am working on and asp.net project

```
<div runat="server" id="Div1" >
    <table border="0">  
        <tr>                
           <td onclick="ShowDivTotalBox()">
               <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Total Value: "  />
               <asp:Label runat="server" Text="0" />
           </td>
        </tr>
    </table>  
</div>



<div id="DivTotalBox" runat="server" visible="false" >
    <div class="DivMessageBoxInner" style="width: 550px;>           
        <table >
            <tr>
                <td>
                </td>
            </tr>                
        </table>               
    </div>                
</div>   

<script type="text/javascript">

        function ShowDivTotalBox() {
            document.getElementById('<%=DivTotalBox.ClientID %>').style.visibility = 'visible';
        }

    </script>
```

It Seems Like Event is not firing. Please help.

Comment: What is the resulting client-side code that this produces?  In your browser's debugging tools, check the console for errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the `visible` property is what you're looking for here. When you set `visible = "false"` on an element with `runat = "server"`, it is not rendered and can not be used in javascript.

Based on your javascript here, I assume you need the `visibility` style property. Try changing your div tag to this:

```
<div id="DivTotalBox" runat="server" style="visibility: hidden">
```

Then, when your javascript should not throw any errors and should show your table. As a test, try adding some text to your `<td>` tag in `table` in `DivMessageBoxInner`.

Comment: thank alot. @dvo, your solution worked. keep the community alive.

Comment: @Asim Glad that worked for you. Please accept this answer so it shows other users the question is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Are you working in webform?
As I remember there is no need to write runat="server" in div
give td unique id like

```
<td id="aTd">
```

and in script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#DivTotalBox").hide();
$("#aTd").on('click', function(e){
e.preventDefault();
$("#DivTotalBox").show();
})})
```

if this doesn't work check your id property in the web by clicking f12
and remove visible=false runat=server onclick stuff in your code

Comment: i need to use runat server becuase i am changing the visibility of of the div from code behind.